# Mac Mouse/Trackpad Speed Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, iokit

I'm trying to change the mouse tracking speed (Notice: Not acceleration) for an application I'm working on. I've searched everywhere for a way to do this, but couldn't find anything.
I suspect that has to do with the value I give in this function on the IOKit/hidsystem Framework:

```
IOHIDSetAccelerationWithKey(handle, CFSTR(kIOHIDMouseAccelerationType), mouseAcceleration);
```

Being mouseAcceleration the value, I suspect there is a hex value that defines both acceleration and speed.

Does anyone came across this problem and could help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a thing as mouse tracking speed which isn't acceleration. What makes you think there is? As I recall, if you change the acceleration programmatically, it changes what's shown in the Tracking slider in System Preferences > Mouse. (You may need to relaunch System Preferences for it to update.)

Answer (score 1):

Working example in swift:

```
func getAcceleration() -> Double {
    var speed:Double = 0
    IOHIDGetAccelerationWithKey(NXOpenEventStatus(), kIOHIDTrackpadAccelerationType, &speed)
    return speed
}

func setAcceleration(_ speed: Double) {
    IOHIDSetAccelerationWithKey(NXOpenEventStatus(), kIOHIDTrackpadAccelerationType, speed)
}
```

Source:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/usb/2004/Aug/msg00056.html

Answer (score -1):

You can try to make [NSTrackingArea](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTrackingArea_class/Reference/Reference.html) and change mouse position after you get new mouse position.