# Change Mac cursor speed programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cursor

I need to slow the cursor speed down for precision movement of the mouse if the user holds a specific key down. Is there an API for doing this? I've tried to get the mouse location and set its position to half of that but it doesn't work.

```
let mouseLoc = NSEvent.mouseLocation

// get the delta
let deltaX = mouseLoc.x - lastX
let deltaY = mouseLoc.y - lastY

lastX = mouseLoc.x; lastY = mouseLoc.y

// add to the current position by half of the real mouse position
var x = currentMousePos.x + (deltaX / 2)
var y = currentMousePos.y + (deltaY / 2)

// invert the y and set the mouse pos
CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(CGMainDisplayID(), carbonPoint(from: currentMousePos))
currentMousePos = NSPoint(x: x, y: y)
```

How do you change the cursor speed?

I've looked at [Mac Mouse/Trackpad Speed Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448843/mac-mouse-trackpad-speed-programmatically) but the function is deprecated.

Comment: I’m aware of this post but they're using a deprecated API: [Mac Mouse/Trackpad Speed Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448843/mac-mouse-trackpad-speed-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to disassociate the cursor position with the mouse, handle events, and move the cursor yourself at a slower rate.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzDisplayServicesConceptual/Articles/MouseCursor.html

```
CGDisplayHideCursor (kCGNullDirectDisplay);
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition (false);
// ... handle events, move cursor by some scalar of the mouse movement
// ... using CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint (kCGDirectMainDisplay, ...);
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition (true);
CGDisplayShowCursor (kCGNullDirectDisplay);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to seths [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47848986/7117009) here's the basic working code:

```
var shiftPressed = false {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != shiftPressed {
            // disassociate the mouse position if the user is holding shift and associate it if not
            CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(boolean_t(truncating: !shiftPressed as NSNumber));
        }
    }
}

// listen for when the mouse moves
localMouseMonitor = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) { (event: NSEvent) in
    self.updateMouse(eventDeltaX: event.deltaX, eventDeltaY: event.deltaY)
    return event
}

func updateMouse(eventDeltaX: CGFloat, eventDeltaY: CGFloat) {
    let mouseLoc = NSEvent.mouseLocation
    var x = mouseLoc.x, y = mouseLoc.y

    // slow the mouse speed when shift is pressed
    if shiftPressed {
        let speed: CGFloat = 0.1
        // set the x and y based off a percentage of the mouse delta
        x = lastX + (eventDeltaX * speed)
        y = lastY - (eventDeltaY * speed)

        // move the mouse to the new position
        CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint(CGMainDisplayID(), carbonPoint(from: NSPoint(x: x, y: y)));
    }

    lastX = x
    lastY = y
}
```